# multiple elements with the same id

Tags: javascript, html, css

i've heard using multiple id attributes is very bad practice but what confuses me is what if the elements are nested like this...

```
<div id="slideshow1" class="slideshow">
    <div id="left" class="slideshow-arrow"></div>
    <div id="right" class="slideshow-arrow"></div>
</div>
<div id="slideshow2" class="slideshow">
    <div id="left" class="slideshow-arrow"></div>
    <div id="right" class="slideshow-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

i've made an example with js here and everything seems to work fine..

http://jsfiddle.net/6YPsX/

if they were nested within the same element then unique id's would make sense but do ID's really need to be unique to the whole document?

Comment: Yes..Id have to be Unique in a Document http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id

Comment: if they elements are nested like this... duplicate ids are still bad practise :) try to add the left/ right as an additional class

Comment: If you call `document.getElementById('left')` what element do you think you'd get?

Comment: @KURN No, they are not "a bad practice", they are explicitly forbidden in the spec.

Comment: Yes, IDs have to be unique no matter what the scope. That includes all the way up to document. Your example works because browsers are forgiving of breaking the spec.

Comment: See this get*Element*ById vs get*Elements*ByClassName

Comment: Dont confuse jsfiddle with a HTML validator!

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Period.

Comment: `"seems to work fine"` - In that specific browser, with that specific code.  Having multiple identical `id`s is invalid and the behavior is undefined.  It *might* work in some scenarios, but it's not guaranteed.  (Note: Never assume that just because you got something to work that means you did it correctly.)

Comment: ok, got it. thanks. i guess an extra class is the way to go here.  or what about this? 

data-id="left"

Comment: Why do you want it to be specifically called an id, you could equally use `data-side-of-screen="left"`

Comment: no reason.. was just wondering why using id more than once is not good. i thought that if each element that had the same id was nested within a different parent it would be fine. like 2 different instances of a class in Java or AS3 for example, both instances would have the same property names. eg-

`var slideShow1 = new SlideShow();
var slideShow2 = new SlideShow();

trace(slideShow1.left);
trace(slideShow2.left);`

i'm still getting used to HTML.. thanks for the answers. i'm clear on this now. cheers

Answer (score 3):

An ID is more than just a way of finding an element, there are other things associated with an ID. The following link should be helpful and provide a greater insight into this. Here are the main points:

The id attribute has several roles in HTML:

- As a style sheet selector. As a target anchor for hypertext links.
- As a means to reference a particular element from a script.
- As the name of a declared OBJECT element.
- For general purpose processing by user
  agents (e.g. for identifying fields when extracting data from HTML
  pages into a database, translating HTML documents into other formats,
  etc.).

[link to w3 site](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple classes on the same element

```
<div id="slideshow1" class="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow-arrow left"></div>
    <div class="slideshow-arrow right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slideshow-arrow {
    background: none top left no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.slideshow-arrow.left {
    background-image: url('...');
}
.slideshow-arrow.right {
    background-image: url('...');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad practice it won't pass W3C validation and it get's even worse when you try to implement JavaScript.  Just use a class name instead or give them different id names.